# Virutal Hosting using XAMPP in AWS EC2 INSTANCE

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, hosting, xampp, codeigniter

Trying to host 2 or more domains in a single aws ec2 instance.

my configuration is:

## host:

18.219.39.37 [my domain]

## httpd.conf:

Listen 80

`<Directory />`
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
`</Directory>`

`#`Virtual hosts

Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

## httpd-xampp.conf:

`#`since XAMPP 1.4.3

    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
    Allow from all

## httpd-vhosts.conf:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`
    ServerAdmin webmaster@[IPv4 Public IP]
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/rustikhaws/public_html/"
    ServerName [IPv4 Public IP]
`</VirtualHost>`

This configuration gives me...

## Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

and I don't know what is lacking in my configuration.

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming a single IP address and 2 sites, both on port 80, which is the most typical setup for http multi hosting)

The ServerName needs to be the domain name, not the IP address, and you need a  VirtualHost section for each domain name.

You don't specify IP address anywhere in the config ( the *:80 in the VirtualHost line answers on all IPs). You specify the domain -> IP address mapping in DNS, which is outside Apache.   For testing purposes you can modify the hosts file on the computer you are testing from.

(This works because the HTTP protocol does not rely on IP address - when a connection is opened to the server, one of the headers the client sends is the host (domain) name it wants information for.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create individual `.conf` files in the `/sites-available/` directory.

If you could post your full sites-enabled config it would be easier to read.

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally in your `httpd.conf` you have specified `AllowOverride none`  if you're hosting Wordpress websites and using permalinks you this setting should be `AllowOverride all`

The error you're receiving is because the URL was not found on the server.

try to enable the site using `a2ensite example.com` within the `sites-available` directory.  This command will create the symbolic links.  In a similar fashion `a2dissite` will disable the website by removing the symbolic link.

Post your full config and I can help you more